# No routes matched location "/" react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React-router-dom v6 and having a problem here. the website is working fine but in the console, it is giving me this error.  "No routes matched location "/" "
can anyone tell me what is the problem? I just transferred from react-router-dom v5 to v6
this is the code of my APP.jsx

```js
import React, { lazy, Suspense, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Screens/Header/Header";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Loading from "./Screens/Global/Loading";
import { useStateValue } from "../StateProvider";
import Home from "./Screens/Home/Home";
import ScrollToTop from "./Screens/Global/ScrollToTop";

const NotFound = lazy(() => import("./Screens/Global/NotFound"));
const Login = lazy(() => import("./Screens/Auth/Login"));
const AllProductsHeader = lazy(() =>
  import("./DevAdmin/Products/AllProductsHeader/AllProductsHeader")
);
const Pay = lazy(() => import("./Screens/Checkout/Pay"));
const RegisteredUsers = lazy(() => import("./DevAdmin/users/RegisteredUsers"));
const Dashboard = lazy(() => import("./DevAdmin/Dashboard/Dashboard"));
const Location = lazy(() => import("./Screens/Location/Location"));
const Order = lazy(() => import("./Screens/Order/Order"));
const Cart = lazy(() => import("./Screens/Cart/Cart"));
const About = lazy(() => import("./Screens/About/About"));
const Orders = lazy(() => import("./Screens/OrderHistory/Orders"));
const Checkout = lazy(() => import("./Screens/Checkout/Checkout"));
const Settings = lazy(() => import("./Screens/Settings/Settings"));
const CreateCategory = lazy(() =>
  import("./DevAdmin/Categories/CreateCategory")
);

const MenuScreen = lazy(() => import("./Screens/Menu/MenuScreen"));
const CreateProduct = lazy(() => import("./DevAdmin/Products/CreateProduct"));
const Register = lazy(() => import("./Screens/Auth/Register"));
const AllProducts = lazy(() =>
  import("./DevAdmin/Products/Products/AllProducts")
);
const PostalCodes = lazy(() =>
  import("./DevAdmin/ManagePostalCodes/PostalCodes")
);
const ManageOrders = lazy(() =>
  import("./DevAdmin/Orders/Orders/ManageOrders")
);
const DashboardHome = lazy(() => import("./DevAdmin/Dashboard/Home/Home"));
const Reports = lazy(() => import("./DevAdmin/Reports/Reports"));

function App() {
  const { userAPI } = useStateValue();
  const [isAdmin] = userAPI.isAdmin;
  const { userID } = userAPI;
  
  
  
  
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          {isAdmin ? (
            <Route
              path="/dashboard"
              element={
                <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                  <Dashboard />
                </Suspense>
              }>
              <Route
                index
                element={
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <DashboardHome />
                  </Suspense>
                }
              />

              <Route
                path="postalcodes"
                element={
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <PostalCodes />
                  </Suspense>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="all_orders"
                element={
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <ManageOrders />
                  </Suspense>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="all_users"
                element={
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <RegisteredUsers />
                  </Suspense>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="products"
                element={
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <AllProductsHeader />
                  </Suspense>
                }>
                <Route
                  index
                  element={
                    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                      <AllProducts />
                    </Suspense>
                  }
                />
                <Route
                  path="create_product"
                  element={
                    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                      <CreateProduct />
                    </Suspense>
                  }
                />
              </Route>
              <Route
                path="create_category"
                element={
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <CreateCategory />
                  </Suspense>
                }
              />

              <Route
                path="all_reservoirs"
                element={
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <ManageOrders />
                  </Suspense>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="reports"
                element={
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <Reports />
                  </Suspense>
                }
              />
            </Route>
          ) : (
            <Route
              path="dashboard/*"
              element={
                <>
                  <Header />
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <NotFound />
                  </Suspense>
                </>
              }
            />
          )}
        </Routes>

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Header />}>
            <Route
              index
              element={
                <>
                  <ScrollToTop />
                  <Home />
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="menu"
              element={
                <>
                  <ScrollToTop />
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <MenuScreen />
                  </Suspense>
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="order"
              element={
                <>
                  <ScrollToTop />
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <Order />
                  </Suspense>
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="checkout"
              element={
                <>
                  <ScrollToTop />
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <Checkout />
                  </Suspense>
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="checkout/paymentOptions"
              element={
                <>
                  <ScrollToTop />
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <Pay />
                  </Suspense>
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="about"
              element={
                <>
                  <ScrollToTop />
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <About />
                  </Suspense>
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="find-us"
              element={
                <>
                  <ScrollToTop />
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <Location />
                  </Suspense>
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="orders"
              element={
                <>
                  <ScrollToTop />
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <Orders />
                  </Suspense>
                </>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="login"
              element={
                <>
                  <ScrollToTop />
                  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                    <Login />
                  </Suspense>
                </>
              }
            />

            <Route
              path="register"
              element={
                <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                  <Register />
                </Suspense>
              }
            />

            <Route
              path="cart"
              element={
                <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                  <Cart />
                </Suspense>
              }
            />

            <Route
              path="settings"
              element={
                <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                  <Settings />
                </Suspense>
              }
            />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any other improvement will be appreciated

Comment: I think you want to wrap all of your `Route`s in one `Routes` component. The first `Routes` has no child `Route` that matches `'/'` but the second one does. Wrap the whole thing in one `Routes` and the error should go away. Unless you need the functionality of two Routes, you're probably better off accomplishing what you are trying to do with one `Routes` and using layout `Route`s. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes

Comment: Thank you. it was helpful send this comment as an answer  I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try having your ternary inside the public `<Routes>` instead of having 2 seperate `Routes`

```js
        <Routes>
          {isAdmin ? (
            <Route
              path="/dashboard"
              element={
                <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                  <Dashboard />
                </Suspense>
              }>
              ...)
           :(...)
          <Route path="/" element={<Header />}>
            <Route
              index
              element={
                <>
                  <ScrollToTop />
                  <Home />
                </>
              }
            />
            ....
          </Route>
            
        </Routes>
```